# How to align the formulas?

Tags: vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{How to vertically align  \ref{first} and \ref{second}?}

    \begin{definition}
        \mbox{}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item\label{first} First line: \hspace{40pt} $ A\leftrightarrow B\wedge C$
            \item\label{second} Second and longer line: \hspace{8pt} $\forall x\forall y\forall z(x<z
            \to (x<y\vee y<z))$
            
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eqparbox`. The first optional argument to `\eqmakebox` isn't really optional, because it's an arbitrary string that identifies the boxes that should be equalized; the second optional argument is the alignment inside the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{How to vertically align  \ref{first} and \ref{second}?}

\begin{definition}\mbox{}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item\label{first}
    \eqmakebox[A][l]{First line:} $ A\leftrightarrow B\wedge C$

  \item\label{second}
    \eqmakebox[A][l]{Second and longer line:}
    $\forall x\forall y\forall z(x<z \to (x<y\vee y<z))$
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

You need two runs when you add a set of equalized boxes (or change their text) for the typesetting to stabilize.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a `\makebox` directive to place the string "First line:" inside a transparent "box" that's as wide as the string "Second and longer line:" is long.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc} % for '\widthof' macro
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{How to vertically align \ref{first} and \ref{second}?}

\begin{definition}
\mbox{}
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{first}
    \makebox[\widthof{Second and longer line:}][l]{First line:}\quad
    $A\leftrightarrow B\wedge C$
\item\label{second}
    Second and longer line:\quad
    $\forall x\forall y\forall z\ (x<z\to (x<y\vee y<z))$
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A very elegant solution!